Html form input field - pattern attribute - allow integers and increments of 0.5
I'm building an html form and one of the fields is for a quantity/length of an item.
Valid values are anything with an increment of 0.5 - therefore 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5
I'm having issues building a regex to put in the "pattern" attribute that will allow both the full and half entries.
I originally had this :
pattern="[0-9]+\.[0-9]"
This allows 0.5, 1.5 etc but fails on integers
I then tried this :
pattern="[0-9]+,[0-9]*\.[0-9]+"
But this fails on all entries.
Anyone got any ideas ?

did you consider using something like <input type="number" step="0.5" min="0">? input type number

Instead of using an input[type=text] and engage its pattern attribute, it could be better to use directly an input[type=number].
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number
Anyway the regex to allow only integer numbers or steps of .5 would be [0-9]+(\.5)?


input:invalid {
  border: red solid 3px;
}
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+(\.5)?">

<input type="number" step="0.5" min="0">



